# Is there a rank 3 boolean interval [H;G] with G simple group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lattice-orders, gap

Let $[H;G]$ be an interval of finite groups.

The rank $n$ boolean lattice $B_{n}$ is the subset lattice of $\{1,2, \dots , n\}$.
For example, for $m = p_1p_2 \dots p_n$ square free, $[1;\mathbb{Z}/m]$ is a rank $n$ boolean lattice.
The lattice  $B_{3}$ is the following:

[image]

*Question*: Is there a rank $3$ boolean interval $[H;G]$ with $G$ simple group?

*Remark*: GAP has found no example for $\vert G \vert <5000$.

Comment: I think this is unlikely, because a subgroup $H$ in such a configuration is generally contained in many more subgroups of $G$. But it might be hard to prove, even using CFSG. What is the motivation for thsi question?

Comment: @DerekHolt:  The motivation is for finding a counter-example for the following post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1123337/84284. Such a simple group does not give a counter-example automatically (for this other post) , but it's a good area for searching (I didn't find a small group counterexample for the other post). Now the motivation for the other post is that I can prove a result on subfactor theory for distributive lattice with $<8$ vertices, but I can't for $L_{30}$ (...)

Comment: (...) So if such a counter-example exists, it could be a counter-example for my result for $L_{30}$, else a proof for the other post could be very useful for my research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $S_n$, the subgroup $S_a\times S_b$, $a+b=n$, $a\not=b$ is maximal. So taking the three maximal subgroups as stabilizers in $S_n$ of disjoint sets of different cardinalities looks like a good place to start for such configurations. Indeed, searching through alternating groups finds the following example (though it is not of this kind that motivated searching through alternating groups...):

If you take $G=A_8$ and $H=t_8n_{29}=[2^3]D(4)$ (of order 64) the condition is satisfied (as found by an explicit computation in GAP:

```
g:=AlternatingGroup(8);
u:=TransitiveGroup(8,29);
int:=IntermediateSubgroups(g,u);
```

In case anyone cares, and to satisfy the (gap)-tag, here is the code I used for searching. It only tests for 6 intermediate subgroups, the final test of the groups then is a hand-inspection of the result of `IntermediateSubgroups`.

```
test:=function(G)
  local m,allmax,m2,m3,mm,i,j,int;
  m:=MaximalSubgroupClassReps(G);
  allmax:=MaximalSubgroups(G);
  Print("|m|=",Length(m),"\n");
  Print("|allmax|=",Length(allmax),"\n");
  m2:=Union(List(m,x->Filtered(MaximalSubgroupClassReps(x),
      y->Number(allmax,z->IsSubset(z,y))=2)));
  Print("|m2|=",Length(m2),"\n");
  m2:=List(SubgroupsOrbitsAndNormalizers(G,m2,false),x->x.representative);
  Print("|m2|=",Length(m2),"\n");
  m3:=[];
  for i in [1..Length(m2)] do
    mm:=Filtered(MaximalSubgroupClassReps(m2[i]),
      y->Number(allmax,z->IsSubset(z,y))=3);
    Print(i,", |mm|=",Length(m2),"\n");
    for j in mm do
      int:=IntermediateSubgroups(G,j);
      if Length(int.subgroups)=6 and Length(int.inclusions)=12 then
        Print("found!\n");
        Add(m3,j);
      fi;
    od;
  od;
  m3:=List(SubgroupsOrbitsAndNormalizers(G,m3,false),x->x.representative);
  return m3;
end;
```

Comment: Is it the smallest example?

Comment: It is the smallest $A_n$, I believe. One could use the above code and `SimpleGroupsIterator` to test all smaller ones, but I have not done so.

Comment: Yes, $A_8$ is the smallest example. The next is $PSU(3,5)$ with a subgroup of *index* $6000$.

Comment: Your function returns an error for $G=PSp(6,2)$ (but works for every simple group of order < $|G|$).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error for $PSp(6,2)$ -- let me know whether you want the result, or send me privately more details about the kind of error. Thanks!